# Query String with AND operator in Elastic Search 8.9

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

To search for the terms "peter" and "estes" in the fields "addr_line1" and "addr_line2" using wildcards, tried using the following query:

It seems something needs to be corrected in the below script. I do get results when I query with either first name or last name in the below script. But when I try to lookup for both the first name and last name I don't see any results.

```
"should": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "*peter* AND *estes*",
                    "analyze_wildcard": true,
                    "fields": [
                        "addr_line1",
                        "addr_line2"
                    ]
                }
            },
```

Comment: Please provide mapping, sample data, expected result and the actual result.